# If $\int_0^1 x^nf(x)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $\int_0^1 x^nf(x)=0$ for all nonnegative integers $n$, where $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function that is bounded. How do you prove that $f(x)=0$ a.e. on $[0,1]$.

I've seen this problem before, except with the condition that $f$ is continuous. In this case, we can use the Weierstrauss Approximation Theorem to approximate $f$. But in this problem we are not given that $f$ is continuous. How to proceed without assuming $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Hint: Use Weierstrass approximation theorem and the fact that continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ to show that $\int_0^1 g(x)f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $g \in L^1([0, 1])$. Then use the fact that $L^\infty([0, 1])$ is the dual space of $L^1([0, 1])$ to finish the proof.